# How well theoretically motivated is $R$-parity?

Tags: supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

I understand that [$R$-parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-parity) is empirically necessary in order to avoid proton decay, but theoretically I'm worried that it amounts to a tune or "hack" that spoils the naturalness argument for supersymmetry. In other words, TeV scale supersymmetry solves the hierarchy problem, but isn't it unnatural to pick one out of a very large space of possible symmetries in order to patch-up the proton decay problem? Is $B-L$ symmetry somehow natural to expect theoretically ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-parity#Possible_origins_of_R-parity) mentions something vague about it arising naturally in $SO(10)$ GUTs)?